# Negotiating Bluetooth LE ATT MTU on Android and iOS central / peripheral in practice

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

On Android we have `requestMtu` and `onMtuChanged`, which seems to imply that we have to manually negotiate MTU sizes, if both central and peripheral devices are Android based (*but I might be wrong and it might be that it happens also automatically upon connection without my intervention*). 
Documentation for `requestMtu` talks only about write request (write without response) operation and does not mention notifications, and also says that it is meant for "connection" but does not mention if it's from central or peripheral side.
**Thus, it's not clear, which side of the connection can/should use `requestMtu` and how it affects both notification size and write size?**

On iOS, it seems, there is no direct alternative to `requestMtu` and we have only `central.maximumUpdateValueLength` (since iOS 7, I guess). Its documentation (on the contrary to the Android one) says that `maximumUpdateValueLength` is for notification updates only, which implies that it is useful only on the peripheral side, since you send notifications from peripheral to central.
**But what about writes? If I'm writing (again without response) to a characteristic from a central to a peripheral, how do I know my batch size to ensure efficient writes?**

Considering mixed systems (Android/iOS central/peripheral), it all gets confusing and it is not clear at all which side and when can/should request/react to MTU size negotiation. **Is there any document describing ATT MTU exchange options, which correspond to real Android and iOS implementation?**

Answer (score 1):

Asper my understanding `requestMtu()` should be initiated from central role device as it knows how much data it is going to transmit n receive. In general, in any client server model it is always the client that tells or negotiates the session parameters. Hence I feel even in the case of BLE the same rule fits.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The confusion is mostly caused because of iOS where there seems to be no documented way to find out how much data central is going to transmit, and also it's not clearly defined whether and how MTU will affect both writes and / or notifications. I did not receive any answers on Apple forums. I guess, I'll have to find it out through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the BLE standard both sides may exchange MTU. The same MTU applies to both when the device acts as client and server.